# Databind formatted data from gridview to new gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, datatable

I have a datatable in Gridview1 and have formatted it by adding several new rows in the datatable, I want to push this data to another table to also include the blank rows as part of the data. How would I go about doing this? What I mean is I want to use the data in my first gridview as a datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your DataTable on into a Session.

Something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Session["DataStore"] = dt;

Gridview1.DataSource= dt;
GridView1.Databind();
```

Then you can use Session["DataStore"] as your datasource .

```
var dt = (DataTable)Session["DataStore"];

GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.Databind();
```

Hipe this Helps

Regards